# Visualizing Data in Java

Tags: java, r, statistics, data-visualization

Is there a good library on the web to visualize big data in Java? Perhaps a library for statistical outputs? I know the programming language R is used to visualize statistical data in R, and I have seen a solution to connect Java and R, but it would be better if I can have a pure Java solution.

Comment: What kind of data are we talkin' here?

Comment: I've always thought the fun part about being a programmer was writing my own code not always relying on other peoples.  There are plenty of chart libraries for Java and JavaScript.

Comment: @ Doomspork, agreed but not having to reinvent the wheel makes it much easier to build your own car.

Answer (score 6):

might want to check out http://processing.org/

Answer (score 5):

I've had success with visualizing graphs with a commercial tool called [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html). For more general purpose statistical data visualization, you could try [Mondrian](http://rosuda.org/mondrian/), which is GPL licensed. These both are Java libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Have to mention [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/) -- using it very frequently. It does not provide the ready to use data structures as Prefuse does, but it surely scales and provides a great degree of freedom in how one would want to visualise the data.

Answer (score 3):

JFreeChart is a good Option. I have tried it, and is easy to set up with Eclipse too. BIRT is also nice, but if you are using it for reporting that is.

Answer (score 3):

Prefuse is a pretty nice library for Java, and even lets you publish animations in Flash using a layer called Flare:

- [prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/)
- [prefuse visualization gallery](http://prefuse.org/gallery/)

On the R side, you only need to browse the gallery to see what it's capable of:

- [R Graphics Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a library for Clojure (not quite Java but still on the JVM) called [Incanter](http://incanter.org/).

It is built on Colt and JFreeChart. It may be possible that you can just use [Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) directly, but I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

The Weka project might be able to help you. It's an open source library of data mining algorithms written in Java. If they don't have the visualization themselves, it might be in their "related projects" section.

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/